# Relation is in 2NF or not?

Tags: database-theory, databases, normal-forms, functional-dependencies

Consider a relation R(A,B,C,D,E) and the only FDs,

ABD->C

BC->D

CD->E

These are the only 3 FDs. I want to know if the above relation is in 2NF or not.

According to the definition of 2NF, a relation to be in 2NF, it should be in 1NF and it should not have partial dependency.

But I'm not getting the partial dependency concept.

Somewhere it's written that when a proper subset of a key determines a non-prime attribute then it is partial dependency.

Somewhere it's written that when a prime attribute which is not a key determines a non-prime attribute then it is partial dependency.

Because of these 2 different definitions I'm getting confused.

Please help.

Comment: Same comments apply after your edit, please act on them. [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: All your definitions are wrong. What is your textbook name & edition? (Though they can be very poor.) PS "These are the only 3 FDs." cannot be. When some FDs hold, others do--per Armstrong's axioms. Others might hold too. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a *cover*. And the set of all attributes. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097) PS ["1NF" has many meanings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) What's yours? PS [Partial Dependency (Databases)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25827210/3404097) PS Ask 1 question, re where you're 1st stuck.

Comment: @philipxy I'm referring books of Henry Korth and Ramakrishnan.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please put what is need to ask in your post including quotes. Please ask exactly 1 clear specific researched non-duplicate question. PS Name & edition & quotes.

Comment: The definition of partial FD in Korth et al is correct. The definition in Ramakrishnan et al is not complete; they only tell you when a FD of the form set->attribute that violates 3nf is partial. (Their definition of transitive FD has the same problem.) (The definition of transitive FD in Korth et al is not complete; they only tell you when a FD of the form set->attribute is transitive.) Pick a textbook & follow it.

Comment: @philipxy Ok. Got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second normal form means that each non prime attribute must not depend on a proper subset of a candidate key.

In your example, assuming that the given FDs are a cover of the FDs of the relation, you have two candidate keys, `ABC` and `ABD`. Moreover, the attribute `E` depends on `BC`, which is a proper subset of the candidate key `ABC` (you can verify this by computing the closure of `BC`, `BC+`, and see that `E` belongs to that closure).

So the relation is not in 2NF.

Comment: Thank you so much